# Get the value of a label from a servlet using java

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to know how can I get the value of a label from the request servlet in Java. Does `getParameter(nameOfLabel)` work for this? Or does it only work for inputs?. Anyhow, I'd like to know how to do so.

Comment: You can use `non-editable` textbox for that..

Comment: Why do you need to get the value of a label anyway?

Comment: It's because I'm being lazy and I need to display some information, and the user has to press a bottom next to that information, but i need the information I'm displaying later on (this information changes).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden `input` with the `value` of the label:

```
<input type="hidden" value="labelValue" name="labelName" />
```

And then use `getParameter("labelName")` to get its value.